# Ayuda en error de procedure or function .............. expects parameter @....... which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

[image: error en procedure de sistema de ventas]

MI PROCEDURE ES:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsertar_detalle_ingreso]
@id_detalle_ingreso int output,
@id_ingreso int, 
@id_producto int,
@precio_compra money,
@precio_venta money,
@precio_especial money,
@precio_especial2 money,
@stock_inicial int,
@stock_actual int,
@fecha_produccion date,
@fecha_vencimiento date
 as
 insert into detalle_ingreso (id_ingreso, id_producto, precio_compra, 
 precio_venta, precio_especial,
 precio_especial2, stock_inicial, stock_actual, fecha_produccion, 
 fecha_vencimiento)
 values (@id_ingreso, @id_producto, @precio_compra,
 @precio_venta, @precio_especial, @precio_especial2,
 @stock_inicial, @stock_actual, @fecha_produccion, @fecha_vencimiento)
```

Answer (score 1):

Claramente el problema está en el momento que tu aplicación llama al Stored Procedure con el cuarto parámetro "@precio_compra". Para encontrar el problema te recomiendo que uses el Analizador de Rendimiento "Profiler" y que reproduzcas el error.
Justo en el moento que tengas el error en la pantalla de tu aplicación paras el Analizador de Rendimiento y buscas la llamada al Procedimiento Almacenado, cuando la tengas lo copias y pegas en el analizador de consultas y ahí encontrarás lo que está pasando. 
Posiblemente estés llamando al Procedimiento con solo tres parámetros o bien te falte alguna coma.
Si la llamada está bien generada deberías ver algo así como:

```
EXEC [dbo].[spinsertar_detalle_ingreso] 
@id_detalle_ingreso = 102,
@id_ingreso = 80, 
@id_producto = 12003,
@precio_compra = 23.32,
@precio_venta = 28.45,
@precio_especial = 25,
@precio_especial2 = 24,
@stock_inicial = 100,
@stock_actual = 50,
@fecha_produccion = '20181224',
@fecha_vencimiento = '20181224'
```

También es posible que en precio_compra tengas algo así como @precio_compra = 23,32, con lo que el sistema se esté liando con los parámetros ya que cuando acaba la parte entera debería empezar el siguiente parámetro. En fin, puede ser por muchas cosas pero estoy casi seguro de que encontrando la llamada que genera tu aplicación con el Profiler y reproduciéndola en el Analizador de Consultas encontrarás el motivo y con ello la solución.

Comment: Si te ha servido mi respuesta por favor, considera marcarla como "La respuesta". Gracias.